# Corda - can I encumber a fungible token? Should I?

Tags: token, corda

I'm experimenting with HTLC in Corda and ideally I'd like to encumber fungible tokens.  The question then arises for me: when I want to unencumber a token, how do I "tell" the transaction builder which token I'm trying to unencumber, if they are fungible?  Should I extend TokenType to add a unique identifier attribute?  Then I'm curious - what happens to that identifier when the tokens are eventually split and recombined?  Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way; or perhaps I just shouldn't encumber fungible tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what HTLC is.

To answer your question, you can make any corda State encumbered, or a token (or both, just extend/implement both). You just have to make sure to implement the correct interfaces.

When you use transactionbuilder you're just going to add the output state, so you don't have to tell transactionbuilder per se. You just want to make sure you construct the output state correctly and the transactionbuilder will use it.

I'm not sure what would would happen if you tried to split an encumbered fungible token, presumably you'd get an error? Ideally though you probably wouldn't need to run into this on an encumbered state anyway.

Try to figure out why your design needs both of these properties as it's certainly not something that happens often.

thanks and good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, and I will ponder it.  But let me put the question this way: